# Auditing relevant data and then extracting it

Tags: powershell, events

I've turned on (and then off again) auditing on our Fileserver (windows 2012r2)
We have about 8 directories that are being written to and have about 50 directories in total.
I have added auditing onto this so we can determine what is reading from it, and writing to it.

However, we also have an offsite copy going on 24/7 which sync's all the directories and files.

So, can I audit within windows to exclude this particular program?
And, what I want to do is use powershell to extract specific information.  When I import a log into a CSV file, all the information is in one cell - The information I need to grab is the source address, and the files.

Any idea or pointers?

Comment: i can't find any way to exclude an app from auditing. however, you can filter after the fact in PoSh. if you want to-the-point advice on how to handle your data, you likely otta add 2 or 3 lines of that data to you Question along with what you want the result from those lines to look like.

Comment: Thanks for the feed back - I didn't think I could exclude an app from auditing.

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to kinda sorta help ... [*grin*]